# How to take substring before "," or "-" or " "?

Tags: sql, string, substring, presto, strpos

I have two datasets in Presto that can be joined with `"po_num"`.

The first dataset has a clean `"po_num"` that's **either 7 or 10 digits**. (e.g. 1234567)

Po_num in the second dataset, however, has extra strings that either starts with `"," or "-" or " ". (e.g. 1234567-1 or 1234567,1 or 1234567 -1)`

I think I need a function to

1) detect a position of 1st non-numeric string in the second po_num and

2) take a substring prior to the position. Or any other way to handle this...

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 7 or 10 digits which you wish to match would always appear continuously, without any other intervening characters, then you may try using [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_like) here:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON REGEXP_LIKE(t2.Po_num, '\b' || t1.po_num || '\b');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp_extract:

```
with your_data as(
select * from (values
'1234567-1','1234567,1','1234567 -1'
)s (po_num)
)

select regexp_extract(po_num,'^(\d*)',1) as po_num  from your_data s
```

Result:

```
po_num

1234567
1234567
1234567
```

And the same using `regexp_split`:

```
select regexp_split(po_num,'[^\d]+')[1] as po_num from your_data s
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just take the first 7 numbers of each (and make sure that they are of the same type - use CAST ( x AS int)) and join.

Comment: the figure could be either 7 or 10 digits.